# Multiple inheritance and super keyword

Tags: solidity

[image]

in picture 1, the last contract S6 when i call super.test() it returns only 5 (it calls only the most right parent contract), but on another code for example: contract H is F, G {
function bar() public override(F, G) {
super.bar();
when i call super.bar() it calls both parent contracts.
Why is that can someone explain, im stuck on this for days

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, you have to explicitly call `S4.test()` in `S5`:

```
function test() public pure virtual override returns (uint) {
    S4.test();
}
```

In general, I recommend using explicit contract names over the `super` keyword.